# Android OS update with out active service

Tags: htc, ota-update

I have an HTC device which we use for development currently running Android 2.2.1. While trying to update it from:

```
Settings > Software update > Check new
```

it shows the following for quite some time and then goes to an error message:

> **Software Update**
>
> Checking for new Software available now.

This phone doesn't have active service right now though I am connected to WiFi. Does this matter? Does Android prevent you from updating the OS if your device is not activated on a cellular carrier?

Comment: I think that check is for OTAs, which come from the provider, so it's not so much being prevented as just not possible.  Have you tried using HTC Sync and an update installer from their website?

Answer (score 1):

No Android doesn't block if you are not on a cellular network. Did a OTA update of my Galaxy Nexus a couple of weeks back without inserting a SIM.

I think HTC has released no more newer builds for your phone hence you don't see it.